# nltk how to give multiple separated sentences

Tags: python, list, nested, nested-lists, flatten

I have list of sentences (each sentence is a list) in English and I would like to fetch ngrams.
For example:

```
sentences = [['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'one'], ['hello','again']]
```

In order to run

> nltk.utils.ngram

I need to flat the list to:

```
sentences = ['this','is','sentence','one','hello','again']
```

But then I get a fault bgram in

> ('one','hello')

.
What is the best way to deal with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain

sentences = list(chain(*sentences))
```

`chain` return a chain object whose `.__next__()` method returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then elements from the next
iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.

or you can do:

```
 sentences = [i for s in sentences for i in s]
```

Comment: actually needed chain(*sentences) and it worked well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can also use list comprehension

```
f = []
[f.extend(_l) for _l in sentences]

f = ['this', 'is', 'sentence', 'one', 'hello', 'again']
```